# Dynamically Call Imported Methods in Typescript

Tags: typescript, import

I want to dynamically call a method of my imported methods without hard coding each function name in methods like switch. Is there any solutions with something like below code?

```
import * as mathFn from './formula/math';

export function loadMethod(fnName: string, params: string){
   mathFn[fnName](params); 
}
```

I have tried this solution

```
type SupportedMathFunction = keyof typeof mathFn;

export function loadMethod(fnName: SupportedMathFunction, params: string){
       mathFn[fnName](params); 
}
```

But it is still incorrect

Is there a solutions for getting method from imported items with item name?

I get the following Error during the compiling Typescript in VSCODE Terminal:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)
at Module.m._compile (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1043:23)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1046:12)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (...\src\functions.ts:11:1)
```

**Update:**

I don't know why this error occurred but after upgrading Node from 12.16.3 to latest 14.15.5 and running npm update this error doesn't appeared any more. but because of jasmine related error I downgraded the ts-node to 8.10.2 based on this question [Jasmine-ts throwing an error about package subpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335931/jasmine-ts-throwing-an-error-about-package-subpath) and finally the code works! with my own solution:

```
type SupportedMathFunction = keyof typeof mathFn;

export function loadMethod(fnName: SupportedMathFunction, params: string){
   mathFn[fnName](params); 
}
```

as well as @Lesiak's Solution witch is more convinient:

```
function loadMethod<K extends keyof typeof mathFn>(fnName: K ): typeof mathFn[K]{
  return mathFn[fnName]; 
}
```

Comment: This code works as is (with the exception of default export, which is available under mathFn['default']. What kind of problem do you have with with the code you posted?

Comment: I've  updated  my question. Loading item with static string works fine but I want to access them with string variables

Comment: Now you have 2 errors in your code. 1: missing `function` keyword. 2. undefined `params`. Also, you may prefer to return the function from loadMethod, not return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following:

```
function loadMethod<K extends keyof typeof mathFn>(fnName: K ): typeof mathFn[K]{
       return mathFn[fnName]; 
}
```

This fixes 2 problems in your code:

- missing `function` keyword
- undefined params

In addition:

- the method returns the loaded method, and does not call it.
- the method is correctly typed, you get right signature for each returned method

Comment: I got the same error with your Solution @Lesiak