# How to solve "Error: package subpath.." while using jasmine-ts?

Tags: node.js, jasmine, node-modules, jasmine-ts

I'm running a nodejs project with jasmine and jasmine-ts

i get these errors when i try to run my tests

> Error: Package subpath './lib/command' is not defined by "exports" in
> D:\Projects - Abzo\Project 2\node_modules\jasmine\package.json
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
> at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:472:9)
> at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:753:3)
> at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
> at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
> at Object. (D:\Projects - Abzo\Project 2\node_modules\jasmine-ts\src\index.ts:143:17)

I tried to downgrade my ts-node version to 8.10.2 like in this stackoverflow question [Jasmine-ts throwing an error about package subpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65335931/jasmine-ts-throwing-an-error-about-package-subpath) but still unsolved.

My script in package.json is `"test":"jasmine-ts"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the in the **exports** property of *jasmine* package.json:

Jasmine exports only the `jasmine.js` file

```
"exports": "./lib/jasmine.js"
```

But in the *jasmine-ts* code there is a require to command file (around row 164)

```
const Command = require("jasmine/lib/command");
```

Now this file is not part of the exports so it throws the error:

> Error: Package subpath './lib/command' is not defined by "exports"

To fix this jasmine need to export also the command file used by `jasmine-ts`.
I tested with the following changes in jasmine `package.json` and solve the problem:

```
"exports": {
  ".": "./lib/jasmine.js",
  "./lib/command": "./lib/command.js"
}
```

Changing the jasmine `package.json` is not a great solution but for now this is the only solution on top of my mind.
I'll try open an issue to jasmine github repository.